# Confidence interval for sum of independent but not identical bernoulli RVs with small sample size

Tags: inference, small-sample, bernoulli-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

I have a small sample size (5 <= N <= 10), and for each sample i, we observe independent $Y_{i}$ where $Y_{i}$ is the sum of 7 independent yes/no responses (i.e. bernoulli experiments), where each response is independent but has a different probability of success. Formally, $Y_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{7} W_{ij}$ and $W_{ij} \sim Bernoulli(p_{j})$. My goal is to perform inference on $E[Y_{i}]$, which I believe is $\sum_{j=1}^{7} p_{j}$. The small sample size also makes this challenging. For any individual $p_{j}$ you could do something like the Agresti-Coull interval to get a confidence interval, but I'd be interested if there are thoughts on how your approach would change when performing inference on the sum of these probabilities.

Comment: This is called the [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution).  Perusing that tag might help you!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thank you, this looks very promising!

Answer (score 1):

The paper "Simple Buehler-optimal confidence intervals on the average success probability of independent Bernoulli trials" by Bancal and Sekatski (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.12558.pdf) would provide one solution.
That paper studies the following problem: given $m$ independent but non-identical Bernoulli draws, produce a one-sided confidence interval for the average of the Bernoulli parameters.

To apply this to your problem, consider that you have $m=7N$ independent Bernoulli draws in the form of $W\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times 7}$, each with $W_{ij}\sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(q_{ij})$.  In your special case we have that $q_{ij}=p_j$.  The paper above gives you a way to put a confidence interval on what they call $\bar q = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^7 q_{ij} / (7N) = \sum_{j=1}^N p_{j} / 7$.  That, in turn, implies a confidence interval on $\sum_{j=1}^N p_j = 7\bar q$ (just multiply the confidence interval from the paper by 7).

**Note**. It might be possible to use the fact that $q_{ij}=p_j$ to enable tighter confidence intervals.  Not sure.